# Angular6 Routing Issue with IE11

Tags: routes, angular6, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to run Angular6 application in IE11. I have integrated a third party OIDC security client for Identity server Login .
I observed that routing is not working in IE 11
So after successfull login , it redirects to a callback URL with a token .The length is around 5000 for the string and as per my code if the request is /callback it should redirect to CallbackComponent which is not happening in IE11

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Reading your "question" I was wondering what your exact problem/question is. Why routing is not working in IE 11? Whether there are workarounds for this? Whether there are settings in order to influence this behaviour? ...?

Comment: @quant updated the issue

Comment: Can you post the related code?